# IE prompts for password when saving an excel file

Tags: asp.net-1.1

File is sent to the client using Response.writefile and content diposition as inline. When user chooses to Save As, they are asked to authenticate with IIS again even though Anonymous access in enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, I'd suggest looking at the ownership of the Excel file. Presumably it would need to be readable and writable by the IUSR.

Answer (score 0):

What is the path of the file when it is being written?

Do the users have the proper permissions to create files?